# MySQL - Getting count of distinct values from 3 tables

Tags: mysql

I have created 3 tables named complete_shifts,incomplete_shifts and incomplete_shift_register. All three tables include 2 columns called employee_no and date. I want to get count of distinct values in employee_no column from all three tables on a specified  date.

Ex: if I specify "***date = 2013-06-13***" then count shuld be **3**. (employee no : **0008,0019,0035**)

**complete_shifts**

```
shift_id |   date   | employee_no | sign_in_at | sign_out_at
```

---

```
1        |2013-06-13|   0008      | 7:05       | 16:05
2        |2013-06-13|   0008      | 7:10       | 16:05
3        |2013-06-14|   0025      | 7:11       | 16:10
```

**incomplete_shifts**

```
 shift_id  |    date   | employee_no |  sign_in_at |sign_out_at
```

---

```
   1       | 2013-06-13|    0019     |   7:08      |
```

**incomplete_shift_register**

```
 shift_id |   date    |employee_no | sign_in_at
```

---

```
  1       | 2013-06-13|   0008     |    7:08
  2       | 2013-06-13|   0035     |    7:09
  3       | 2013-06-14|   0060     |    7:11
```

i don't know how to write the SQL syntax for above situation... plezzz help me..

thank you.

Comment: Isn't the definition of an incomplete shift simply one with no sign_out_at? Why do you need a separate table for this!?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT count(*) from 
(
SELECT 1 from complete_shifts WHERE date="2013-06-13"
UNION ALL
SELECT 1 from incomplete_shifts WHERE date="2013-06-13"
UNION ALL
SELECT 1 from incomplete_shift_register WHERE date="2013-06-13"
)t
```

Answer (score 1):

How about something like

```
SELECT  COUNT(DISTINCT employee_no) cnt_employee_no
FROM    (
    SELECT  employee_no
    FROM    complete_shifts
    WHERE   date = '2013-06-13'
    UNION 
    SELECT  employee_no
    FROM    incomplete_shifts
    WHERE   date = '2013-06-13'
    UNION 
    SELECT  employee_no
    FROM    incomplete_shift_register
    WHERE   date = '2013-06-13'
    )
```

Using

[UNION Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html)

> UNION is used to combine the result from multiple SELECT statements
>   into a single result set.

and

[COUNT(DISTINCT expr,[expr...])](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count-distinct)

> Returns a count of the number of rows with different non-NULL expr
>   values.

Answer (score 0):

Just `UNION` the tables together and `COUNT`. The `UNION` will remove duplicates, so a simple `COUNT` will do the trick - a `COUNT DISTINCT` won't be needed. This will work if you want the count only; if you want other values the query gets slightly more involved:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
  SELECT employee_no
    FROM complete_shifts
    WHERE date = '2013-06-13'
  UNION SELECT employee_no
    FROM incomplete_shifts
    WHERE date = '2013-06-13'
  UNION SELECT employee_no
    FROM incomplete_shift_register
    WHERE date = '2013-06-13'
 ) AllShifts
```